# Removing elements from list above/below certain value

Tags: prolog

I have written a small Prolog script which, taken a list, removes all values below a threshold N:

```
rem_under([], []).
rem_under([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    X >= 10,
    rem_under(Xs, Ys).
rem_under([X|Xs], Ys) :-
    X < 10,
    rem_under(Xs, Ys).
```

So, for example:

```
2 ?- rem_under([2,15,16,3,5,19],L).
L = [15, 16, 19]
```

I then wanted to make a similar function which removed all elements ABOVE a threshold N:

```
rem_over([], []).    
rem_over([X|Xs], [Ys]) :-
    X > 10,
    rem_over(Xs, Ys).
rem_over([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    X <= 10,
    rem_over(Xs, Ys).
```

Which however returns:

```
1 ?- rem_over([2,15,17,6],L).
false.
```

Any idea why this is? Other than a few cosmetic changes, I have only swapped the < and > signs.

Comment: For the non-greater than test, use `=<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: It is surprising that your system does not produce an error for `(<=)/2`. Could it be that you ignored the compiler messages?

Comment: Fixed, thanks, and no, no error.... Weird

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 32 bits, Version 6.6.6)

Comment: I have 6.5.2, 7.1.15 and they all barf on `X <= 10.`

Comment: Then, `rem_over([11],L).` succeeds with `L = [[]]`. But it should be `L = []`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second clause is incorrect, because its second argument is `[Ys]` — a list of length 1:

```
rem_over( [X|Xs] , [Ys] ) :-
X > 10,
rem_over(Xs, Ys).
```

Once you've decided the head of the source list is greater than 10, you recurse down on the tail of the source list and the the *contents* of the result list.

Try this:

```
rem_over( []     , [] ) .      % source list exhausted? success!
rem_over( [X|Xs] , Ys ) :-     % source list non-empty?
  X > 10,                      % - head greater than the threshold?
  rem_over(Xs, Ys)             % - chuck it and recurse down on the remainder of the source list
  .                            %
rem_over( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- % source list non-empty? add the head to the result
  X =< 10,                     % - IF it's less than or equal to the threshold
rem_over(Xs, Ys).              % - then recurse down on the remainder
```

Another way to get there:

```
rem_over( []     , [] ) .
rem_over( [X|Xs] , Ys ) :-
  ( X > 10 -> Y1 = Ys ; Y1 = [X|Ys] ) ,
  rem_over(Xs,Y1)
  .
```

Answer (score 0):

HINT: because you have a singleton variable (that is considered to be a list) inside [].

ANSWER: in the head of the 2nd clause should be

> rem_over([X|Xs], Ys) :-

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: ok. I just wanted to give a hint that was quite close to the answer.